# In search of a noun

Tags: nouns

I have learnt that a person who lodges a complaint is referred to as the complainant. How do I then refer to a person who sends a compliment?

Comment: 1. At least one dictionary defines 'complimenter' http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/complimenter  2. There is no word *plauditor* which is a shame because it would be a great option.

Comment: Why the mysterious downvote? This seems a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest ***laudator*** or ***plauditor***. Contrary to what @chasly from UK says the latter does exist and is in the OED, with a distinguished history. The most recent example, from 1995, I was pleased to discover was from one Philip Giddings, who happens to be an old Politics tutor of mine at the University of Reading.

> A person who applauds; a person who praises or expresses approval.
>
> 1688   J. Barker Poet. Recreations v. 54   Amongst his wond'ring
>   Auditors, Who cou'd not chuse where Wit was so profound, And Vertue
>   did so much abound, But to become his faithfull Plauditors.
>
> 1813   S. T. Coleridge Lett. II. 604   No dramatic author ever had so
>   large a number of unsolicited, unknown, yet predetermined plauditors
>   in the theatre, as I had.
>
> 1885   Atlantic Monthly Feb. 277/1   His next proceeding was to
>   advance among the plauditors and bestow various hearty thwacks of the
>   bladder with admirable impartiality.
>
> 1923   Times 19 Feb. 7/4   It is something to hold an audience silent
>   and not coughing through the half-hour of a Brahms sonata, and to
>   restrain the headlong plauditor, who usually breaks in between the
>   movements.
>
> 1995   P. Giddings in D. Shell & R. Hodder-Williams Churchill to Major
>   ii. 31   It should not be surprising, given the flexibility of the
>   office, that both critics and plauditors should find evidence to
>   support their views.

Answer (score 0):

[Flatterer](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/flatterer)

> *flatter*: To compliment excessively and often insincerely, especially in order to win favor.

Synonyms (the same source):

> ass-kisser, crawler, sycophant, toady, lackey - a person who tries to please someone in order to gain a personal advantage

It seems that the language reflects that we do not trust people sending compliments so we have mostly pejorative words for such behaviour :)

Answer (score 0):

**Laudator**

A "laudator" pays hommage, applauds, honors or expresses a favorable judgment.

**Eulogist**

A "eulogist" is a person who praises another person or thing.

**Panegyrist**

A "panegyrist" delivers a formal speech or piece of writing praising a person or event, without any critical spirit.